# paintComponent() and JColorChooser

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, jcolorchooser

I am trying to write a program for class and I am stuck. I need to create a shape (my initial) and then fill it with it JColorChooser. I have been able to create my initial using paint, and graphics. Then I have been able to fill my shape by using g.setColor(new Color(11, 139, 198)); I don't know how to add a JColorChooser to this. This is my first post so let me know whatever I can do to make it easier to read.
Here is my code:

```
/* Program - Letter 
 * Program Desc - 
 * Programmer - Bradon Fredrickson
 * Class - 
 * Created - Oct 1, 2014
 */
package letter;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Letter
{

    public static void PlainLetter()
    {
        /*
         * Creating GUI for letter
         */
        LetterDraw plainLetter = new LetterDraw();
        JFrame logo = new JFrame("My Logos");
        JLabel plain = new JLabel("Plain Letter");
        plain.setLocation(10, 0);
        plain.add(plainLetter);
        Container pane = logo.getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        logo.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // Center the frame
        logo.add(plainLetter);
        logo.setVisible(true);
        logo.setSize(400, 200);
        logo.setLocation(400, 200);
        logo.setVisible(true);
        logo.setDefaultCloseOperation(logo.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }//end plain letter

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PlainLetter();
        new ColorChooser();
    }//end main method
}//end Letter
```

Second class - this is drawing my object

```
/* Program - ThirdLetter 
 * Program Desc - 
 * Programmer - Bradon Fredrickson
 * Class - 
 * Created - Oct 6, 2014
 */

package letter;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LetterDraw extends JPanel
{

    /*
     * Creating my shape/letter
     */
    public void paint(Graphics graphics)
    {

        Path2D.Double path = new Path2D.Double();
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) graphics;
        path.moveTo(17, 63);
        /*
         * Top Horizontal Line
         */
        path.curveTo(21, 60, 21, 43, 17, 37); //left vert
        path.curveTo(30, 43, 100, 43, 120, 37); //top horiz
        path.curveTo(115, 45, 115, 57, 117, 62); //right vert
        path.curveTo(105, 53, 60, 57, 17, 63); //bottom horiz right
        /*
         * Bottom Horizontal Line
         */
        path.moveTo(32, 97);
        path.curveTo(37, 85, 35, 79, 35, 77); //left vert
        path.curveTo(45, 79, 45, 79, 100, 79); //top left horiz
        path.curveTo(96, 85, 98, 92, 98, 98);//right vert
        path.curveTo(89, 93, 79, 94, 32, 97);//bottom right horiz
        /*
         * Vertical Line
         */
        path.moveTo(40, 130);
        path.curveTo(48, 110, 46, 70, 37, 55); //left vert
        path.curveTo(62, 55, 62, 55, 60, 55); //top horiz
        path.curveTo(68, 80, 68, 100, 63, 130); //right vert
        path.curveTo(60, 127, 50, 127, 40, 130);//bottom horiz
        g.setRenderingHint(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
        //g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 0));
        g.draw(path);
        g.setColor(new Color(11, 139, 198));
        g.fill(path);
    }//end paint
}//end LetterDraw
```

third - this is my colorChooser

```
/* Program - ColorChooser 
 * Program Desc - 
 * Programmer - Bradon Fredrickson
 * Class - 
 * Created - Oct 10, 2014
 */
package letter;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.colorchooser.ColorSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class ColorChooser
{

    /**
     * Creating the color chooser
     */
    public ColorChooser()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JColorChooser Popup");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JLabel label = new JLabel("www.java2s.com", JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 48));

        frame.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        final JColorChooser colorChooser = new JColorChooser(label.
                getBackground());

        ColorSelectionModel model = colorChooser.getSelectionModel();
        ChangeListener changeListener = new ChangeListener()
        {
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent changeEvent)
            {
                Color newForegroundColor = colorChooser.getColor();
                label.setForeground(newForegroundColor);
            }
        };
        model.addChangeListener(changeListener);

        frame.add(colorChooser, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }//end colorChooser
}//end colorChooser class
```

Right now i get to 2 JFrames 1 for my shape and 1 for the JColorChooser. I would like to put them all in 1 frame also.

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `LetterDraw` class, instead of doing

```
g.setColor(new Color(11, 139, 198));
```

better to have a class member `Color color`, and have a setter for it. Then do just do this

```
public class LetterDraw extends JPanel {
    private Color color = Color.BLUE; // default;

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        ...
        g.setColor(color);
    }
}
```

Notice the `paintComponent` and `super.paintComponent`. See link from @trashgod in comments.

As for the color selection, [`JColorChooser`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JColorChooser.html) has a  static method, from which you can call to show a color chooser dialog and obtain a returned color from. You can then use that color to call `setColor` on the `LetterDraw`. No need to create your own frame. For instance.

```
Color color = JColorChooser.showDialog(null, "title", Color.BLUE);
letterDraw.setColor(color);
```

If you want to keep the color chooser frame open though and have the , using your current code, You would need to either use some kind of MVC/Observer design, or pass the instance of `LetterDraw` to the `ColorChooser` constructor, so that it can call `LetterDraw's` set color method, after it changes color.

> "I would like to put them all in 1 frame also"

I just noticed that part of the question.

You could forget that `ColorChooser` class all together and create the `JColorChooser` in the `Letter` class. So you have access to the `LetterDraw` object.  Here's how a refactor might look

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Letter {

    LetterDraw letterDraw = new LetterDraw();

    public Letter() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel letterDrawWrapper = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        letterDrawWrapper.add(letterDraw);
        frame.add(letterDrawWrapper);
        frame.add(createColorChooser(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JColorChooser createColorChooser() {
        JColorChooser colorChooser = new JColorChooser();
        colorChooser.getSelectionModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                letterDraw.setColor(colorChooser.getColor());
            }
        });
        return colorChooser;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Letter();
            }
        });
    }
}

class LetterDraw extends JPanel {

    private Color color;

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paintComponent(graphics);
        Path2D.Double path = new Path2D.Double();
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) graphics;
        path.moveTo(17, 63);
        /*
         * Top Horizontal Line
         */
        path.curveTo(21, 60, 21, 43, 17, 37); //left vert
        path.curveTo(30, 43, 100, 43, 120, 37); //top horiz
        path.curveTo(115, 45, 115, 57, 117, 62); //right vert
        path.curveTo(105, 53, 60, 57, 17, 63); //bottom horiz right
            /*
         * Bottom Horizontal Line
         */
        path.moveTo(32, 97);
        path.curveTo(37, 85, 35, 79, 35, 77); //left vert
        path.curveTo(45, 79, 45, 79, 100, 79); //top left horiz
        path.curveTo(96, 85, 98, 92, 98, 98);//right vert
        path.curveTo(89, 93, 79, 94, 32, 97);//bottom right horiz
            /*
         * Vertical Line
         */
        path.moveTo(40, 130);
        path.curveTo(48, 110, 46, 70, 37, 55); //left vert
        path.curveTo(62, 55, 62, 55, 60, 55); //top horiz
        path.curveTo(68, 80, 68, 100, 63, 130); //right vert
        path.curveTo(60, 127, 50, 127, 40, 130);//bottom horiz
        g.setRenderingHint(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
        //g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 0));
        g.draw(path);
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fill(path);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(150, 150);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try this out a little bit later today, but that looks like that is what I need!! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply on this, had a busy weekend and just got around to updating my code. Thank you so much this is exactly what I needed. I had been trying for days and I was getting closer but I don't know if I ever would have figured it out. I am trying to understand everything that you did. What exactly does the Dimension getPrefferedSize() method do? Is that how you got my shape centered at the top of the JFrame?

Comment: `getPreferredSize()` gives a `preferredSize` to the panel. Some layout managers will use this preferredSize to size the panel. The JFrame, has a default `BorderLayout` which doesn't care about the preferredSize. It will stretch the panel to fit. Tha't what I wrapped your drawing panel in another panel, using a `GridBagLayout`, which does respect the preferredSize. If I didn't set the preferredSize and didn't wrap the panel, the panel would be stretched to the edges of the frame, and the x,y coordinates would cause the drawing to be towards the top left

Comment: You can play around with it by taking out the wrapper panel and changing the layout managers, and you will see the differences. For more information on layout managers, see [Laying Out Components Withing a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: As for the centering, `GridBagLayout` by default centers components you add to it. So the wrapper panel, when the drawing panel is added to it, centers the drawing panel. Also when playing around with it, set a border for the draiwng panel, so you can see the changes better. Something like `setBackground(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK, 3));`